# Reusing a buffer binding between VAO and old VBO

Tags: opengl

Assume I have a VAO which I assigned a VBO with id A via glVertexAttribPointer at index 0. Now I delete the VBO via glDeleteBuffers. A new VBO is created via glGenBuffers that coincidentally again receives id A. Now my question: If I want to use this new VBO in place of the old one with the VAO, with the same parameters, do I have to call glVertexAttribPointer again even if the ids of the VBOs are the same?

Comment: *Do I have to call `glVertexAttribPointer` again.*" - Yes. `glGenBuffers` does not generate a buffer object, it reserves an object id, which can be used for a buffer object.

Comment: Of course, I will still call glBufferData on the new VBO. Basically the question is whether the VAO only stores the VBO id internally and not something that gets destroyed with glDeleteBuffers.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you search for the soul of the VBO? You said that you reserve a new buffer id by `glGenBuffers`, so you have to specify the vertex attribute again (with the new buffer id). Anyway *VERTEX ATTRIB ARRAY BUFFER BINDING* is a part of the Vertex Array  Objects state vector. The buffer is identified by its ID. ([Vertex Array Object sates](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=607&zoom=100,168,173))